# Python re.search re.sub string

Tags: python, regex, string, split, expression

I have a file name which always ends on a number proceeding with its file extension such as:

```
filename = 'photo_v_01_20415.jpg'
```

From its filename I need to extract the file_extension and the last number that sits right before the file extension itslelf. As a result of split I should have two strings:

```
original_string = 'photo_v_01_20415.jpg'

string_result_01 = `photo_v_01_`  (first half of the file name)

string_result_02 = `20415.jpg`    (second half of the file name).
```

The problem is that the incoming filenames will be inconsistent. 
The last number could be separated from its file_name by underscore "_", by empty space " ", by period "." or anything else. Example of possible file names:

```
photo_v_01_20415.jpg
photo_v_01.20415.jpg
photo_v_01 20415.jpg
photo_v_01____20415.jpg
```

It appears I need to be using re. expressions with re.search or re.sub. I would appreciate for any suggestions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `re.match` instead of `re.search` to match all of the string to the pattern. Thus

```
import re

def split_name(filename):
    match = re.match(r'(.*?)(\d+\.[^.]+)', filename)
    if match:
        return match.groups()
    else:
        return None, None

for name in [ 'foo123.jpg', 'bar;)234.png', 'baz^_^456.JPEG', 'notanumber.bmp' ]:
    prefix, suffix = split_name(name)
    print("prefix = %r, suffix = %r" % (prefix, suffix))
```

Prints:

```
prefix = 'foo', suffix = '123.jpg'
prefix = 'bar;)', suffix = '234.png'
prefix = 'baz^_^', suffix = '456.JPEG'
prefix = None, suffix = None
```

Works for arbitrary suffixes; if the filename does not match the pattern, then the match fails, and None, None is returned.

Answer (score 3):

```
import re

names = '''\
photo_v_01_20415.jpg
photo_v_01.20415.jpg
photo_v_01 20415.jpg
photo_v_01____20415.jpg'''.splitlines()

for name in names:
    prefix, suffix = re.match(r'(.+?[_. ])(\d+\.[^.]+)$', name).groups()
    print('{} --> {}\t{}'.format(name, prefix, suffix))
```

yields

```
photo_v_01_20415.jpg --> photo_v_01_    20415.jpg
photo_v_01.20415.jpg --> photo_v_01.    20415.jpg
photo_v_01 20415.jpg --> photo_v_01     20415.jpg
photo_v_01____20415.jpg --> photo_v_01____  20415.jpg
```

---

The regex pattern `r'(.+?[_. ])(\d+\.[^.]+)$'` means

```
r'             define a raw string
(              with first group
     .+?           non-greedily match 1-or-more of any character
     [_. ]         followed by a literal underscore, period or space
)              end first group 
(              followed by second group
     \d+           1-or-more digits in [0-9]
     \.            literal period
     [^.]+         1-or-more of anything but a period
)              end second group 
$              match the end of the string
'              end raw string
```

Comment: I've corrected my answer using parts of Antti Haapala solution; apologies to Antti Haapala, I just couldn't stand my answer being wrong. I'll leave my answer up mainly because it explains what the regex means.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

matcher = re.compile('(.*[._ ])(\d+.jpg)')
result = matcher.match(filename)
```

Add other options to the [._ ] as necessary.

Comment: This solution works very well:                                                                                prefix, suffix = re.search(r'(.+?[_. ])(\d+.jpg)$', seq_name).groups()     But the file extension will not be always 'jpg'. How could I tweak this expression to make it valid for any other than jpg file formats?